# Who do you think is he?

Tags: questions, indirect-question

What is the question (do you think) inside the main question?
Is there any name given to this sentence (do you think)?
Is it correct to say "Whom do you think is he?"?
If not, then, why?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What do you mean by "main sentence"? Are you talking about the question in the title? It's not worded normally, but I'm not completely sure it's ungrammatical.

Comment: We'd normally ask "Who do you think he is?".

Comment: Here 'who is he' is the main question, 'do you think' is inserted in the middle. Is this a parenthetical sentence?

Comment: You need to put all that clarification in the question.

Comment: Yes, the question is really unclear.

Comment: "Who is he?"=direct speech Compare: "Who do you think he is."=indirect speech. [not whom, there is no direct object here]. compare: Whom did you see? Notice the action verb.

Answer (score 0):

The correct form is "Who do you think he is?"

"Who is he" is **not** the main question.  Grammatically, the main question is "**Do you think** ([that] he is who)?" ('who' is the unknown item in both questions).  'Do you think' has a question forming fronted auxiliary (from 'You do think').  The clause that is *thought about* ("he is who?") is secondary -- it does not change to the question format ("who is he").  The unknown item 'who[m]' gets fronted before everything.  'Whom' would be the accusative form, but 'who' is proper because it is a subject complement, and also acceptable because it has been fronted.

Comment: "Who" is proper because it is a subjective pronoun. "Who do you think he is?" "I think he's he (subject pronoun)." "Whom" would be proper in an objective sense. "Who is he talking to?" "He is talking to him (object pronoun)." A subject complement is merely an adjective, noun, or pronoun following a copula. Here is an example of a subject complement: "It (subject) is (copula or linking verb) he (pronoun as subject complement) who went on the trip."

Comment: It is true, however, that, technically speaking, subject pronouns have to follow to-be verbs. Most people do not do this, and so this rule isn't widely practiced in informal English. "It is just me at the door" is informal and technically incorrect whereas "It is just I at the door" is more formal and technically correct.

Comment: @Nathan M - Being at the front does not make it the subject.  Before it was fronted, it was a *pronoun following a copula*, making it a subject complement.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your answer. Could you clarify?

Comment: I didn’t understand the question, but I found this answer (and comments) to be very informative.

Comment: Colliding comments... I never meant that the accusative form should be used (although it is quite common).  I do say that the fronted 'who' is still a subject complement, because that is what it is in "He is who?"

Comment: But "He is who?" wasn't the question. In the question asked, "who" is not a subject complement; it is an interrogative pronoun

Comment: Both 'who' and 'whom' are interrogative pronouns, but that doesn't address the semantic role.  "He is who?" really is the embedded question, but not the main one.

Comment: "Who" and "whom" are both interrogative pronouns, but there is a big difference between them: "Who" is a subject pronoun and "whom" is an object pronoun.

Comment: No more chat... please reread fully.

Comment: So, what about this sentence  "Who did you say was going to take your photograph?" Is it the same as we were talking about?

Comment: Yes, in that "You did say [that] ...?" is the main question (with fronted aux), but the fronted pronoun from the embedded question "Who was going to take your photograph?"  is a subject rather than a subject complement (it wouldn't need to be fronted if the embedded question stood alone).

Comment: Direct speech: Who is he? Indirect speech: Who do you think he is? Not: Who do you think is he? This answer is correct. The reversal is removed in indirect speech.